# Cloudwatch Alarms per Lambda Aliases

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

We are using [lambda aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html) **as stages** for our serverless application, and those aliases **point to different versions of a same function**.

Example

Lambda: **MyLambdaConsumer**

| ALIAS | Version |
| --- | --- |
| PROD | 10 |
| QA | 11 |
| DEV | $LATEST |

This approach fits us well for our needs.

However, **we're facing problem creating alerts for each stage**. We've noticed that Cloudwatch Log Streams groups stream **ONLY** by version, and we couldn't restrict those alarms per alias (stage).
In order words, current alarms are going off indistinguible, which turns out to be inaccurate for our needs

Here's how **log stream** of Cloudwatch groups stream by **lambda version**

[image]

So my question is whether there is a way of creating CW Alarms per **ALIAS**.

Just to give a bit more of contextualization, this lambda of mine is a consumer of a SQS queue.

Comment: I am little bit confused, the loggroups are different from the metrics, you can find the lambda metrics by name in the cloudwatch metrics and create alarm on top of them. I might misunderstand something....

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, sorry. Let me try to explain. I've configured a few alarms from lambda metrics by function name and that's working just fine. The problem is that we have aliases as environments, and we can't query by it. Basically, my alarms are going off because of any alias. Did you get the point? I am looking for a way to have alarms per lambda alias

Comment: @SándorBakos I improved the question. Please, let me know whether it sounds clearer now

Comment: Ok, So you can create CW Alarms based on metrics. Lambda has default metrics like: Invocations, Errors, DeadLetterErrors, DestinationDeliveryFailures Throttles  etc... You can check it out in the console and there is a tab inside the Lambda CloudWatch logs where you can select the metrics by ExecutedVersions. Now With this you can monitor runtime errors, and other useful not log related values.
The thing with the loggroups, you can create metrics-filter on top of them and you can monitor certain events occuring based on the logs, it filters it,

Comment: but that is the harder way to construct the filter expression, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I should have searched the metric **by Resource**

[image]

As we can see, resources are grouped by **alias**

Actually, [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html) states exactly it here

> By Executed Version (ExecutedVersion) – View metrics for a combination
> of alias and version. Use the ExecutedVersion dimension to compare
> error rates for two versions of a function that are both targets of a
> weighted alias.

Maybe the label **by resource** itself got me confused. Does not seem to be related to aliases

I created my alarm using terraform, so in order to have it limited to a certain alias, I just added the dimension bellow, informing a function name and a resource (function name + alias)

```
dimensions = {
    Resource     = "corona-skill-dev-status:${var.environment}"
    FunctionName = "corona-skill-dev-status"
  }
```

Comment: I am using weighted alias for deployment for gradual traffic shifting. I would like to set an alarm on  errors of a new version of an alias. I have found `ExecutedVersion` dimension, but how can I specify the value of `ExecutedVersion` from terraform or cloudformation?

Comment: what about custom metrics? for the metrics created by AWS by default, this approach looks fine. But if you create custom metrics on your Lambda function, you cannot specify which alias generated those logs.